# Godaddy does not receive an error response mail

Tags: php, gmail, godaddy

I have developed an application in Laravel 5.5 that sends some emails.

If an error occurs in the recipient (non-existent account, space limit, etc.), we are not receiving bounce as an answer, an email with the typical error:

"Mail Delivery Subsystem ...".

¿That could be happening?

The configuration is:

- Shared hosting on Godaddy
- G Suite por emails (MX records)
- Laravel sending emails with localhost (not gmail)

Comment: You should double-check your G Suite settings. This is likely where things are going awry. Besides MX your records, you should look at `Apps > G Suit > Gmail > Advanced settings`. Check the `Routing` section and make sure you have the correct settings for receiving your mail. You may want to look at [general routing for your domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084) as well as this [overview of email routing and delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650). If you route mail to another server (not Google), that server needs to setup correctly as well.

Comment: Anaksunaman I'm totally lost. Should not bounced messages return automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance if I misunderstand anything in your question, go over anything your already know or make any mistakes/omissions in my explanation =).

> If an error occurs in the recipient (non-existent account, space limit, etc.), we are not receiving [a] bounce [notification], an email with the typical error: "Mail Delivery Subsystem ..."

I am going to assume that you know for certain a [bounce message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) should be returned and that the receiving servers aren't using [catch-alls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all) or simply silently dropping your mail (both are possible).

> Should not bounced messages return automatically?

They are delivered automatically, yes, assuming they are created at all (see above).

However, bounce notifications are often routed via a [bounce address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address), a return path specified in the headers for the email message at the time it is sent. This is often a single return address, so this is where your MX records with Google might come in to play. Importantly, this is not just the normal `From` address. Regarding troubleshooting, this return path is generally listed as the `Return-Path` header once an email is delivered to a recipient.

There is also the small issue of who generates any bounce messages. Effectively, the last [MTA / MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) or program that actual handles a given email is the one responsible for generating bounce notifications. This has potential implications for solving any issues.

*Who Generates A Bounce Notification?*

In the case a message is accepted (e.g. the recipient exists) but another error occurs after that (e.g. the disk runs out of space), then the receiver is responsible for generating any bounce notification and sending it via the proper return path (see above).

If a message is rejected by the receiver (e.g. the recipient does not exist) then the sender (potentially your application) is responsible for generating/handling any bounce notifications.

In either case, Godaddy may not be involved at all (Laravel has a few [options for mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail) and you never specify how emails are generated by localhost, so it's hard to judge Godaddy's potential involvement in this).

*Troubleshooting Your Situation*

I would start by check everything related to Google and confirm your general email messages are being received correctly (MX records define which servers receive mail for a given domain, regardless of who the domain is registered through).

Regarding your application, you don't give much detail. I understand Laravel can handle incoming email, but I know nothing about that kind of setup. Since you say your application sends mail via localhost, at a guess, you might need to specify the correct headers for a bounce return path (again, see above).

Normally, an MTA will specify the return path (sometimes referred to as the "envelope sender"). In this case (with PHP), this header is also called the `From Address` , again not to be confused with the normal `From` address. I am not familiar with Laravel so I can't give any specific steps but, from basic Googling, this value apparently seems like it can be set within the framework.

**Useful Test Addresses**

As a side note, you may be interested in the test email addresses lifted from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699307/service-for-testing-bounced-email-handling). These two addresses, *bouncetest@tribulant.com* and *bounce-test@service.socketlabs.com*, do nothing but bounce emails and thus are useful for testing how your system handles these kinds of messages.

Comment: Thanks!. I have tested using bouncetest@tribulant.com. If I send from gmail, I receive the bounce. If I send from Laravel, not. I think the problem is from Laravel I am not using gmail. I am using local mail. Any help?